# pandas not finding the duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I am having a problem with pandas drop_duplicates and duplicated. It is not finding all the duplicates. Do you know of a work around? Below is my code.

```
# df_a is all the data combined. dp_r1 was from read_csv & dp_r2 was from read_excel.
df_a = pd.concat([df_a, dp_r1, dp_r2], ignore_index=True)

df_a["AC"] = df_a["AC"].str.strip()
df_a["PS Code"] = df_a["PS Code"].str.strip()
df_a["UoM"] = df_a["UoM"].str.strip()
df_a["LTRL"] = df_a["LTRL"].str.strip()
df_a["UoM"] = df_a["UoM"].str.upper()
# ____________________________

subset = ["AC", "LTRL", "PS Code", "Sample Date", "Sample Time", "UoM"]
df_a = df_a.drop_duplicates(subset=subset, keep=False)
# this print below showed over 600 values that should have been dropped.
#print('values of source', df_a.Source.value_counts()) 

# lets just focus on one 'AC' value. 
tds = df_a[df_a['AC']=='1930']
tds = tds[tds['PS Code']=='CA3310012_012_012']
print('tds shape 88:', tds.shape)
tds['duplicated'] = tds.duplicated(subset=subset, keep=False)
print('tds shape 90:', tds.shape)
tds.to_csv(path + 'testing/tds_testing.csv', index=False)
```

Results below from above...

> tds shape 88: (70, 10)
>
> tds shape 90: (70, 11)

I place just part of the table below.

| PS Code | Sampling Point Name | Sample Date | Sample Time | AC | Analyte Name | Result | UoM | LTRL | Source | duplicated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CA3310012_012_012 | Machado | 4/5/2021 | 12:40:00 | 1930 | TDS | 688 | MG/L | N | WT | FALSE |
| CA3310012_012_012 | MACHADO | 5/5/2021 | 9:04:00 | 1930 | TDS | 68 | MG/L | N |  | FALSE |
| CA3310012_012_012 | Machado | 5/5/2021 | 9:04:00 | 1930 | TDS | 680 | MG/L | N | WT | FALSE |
| CA3310012_012_012 | MACHADO | 6/9/2021 | 13:15:00 | 1930 | TDS | 77 | MG/L | N |  | FALSE |
| CA3310012_012_012 | Machado | 6/9/2021 | 13:15:00 | 1930 | TDS | 778 | MG/L | N | WT | FALSE |
| CA3310012_012_012 | MACHADO | 7/8/2021 | 10:30:00 | 1930 | TDS | 7 | MG/L | N |  | FALSE |
| CA3310012_012_012 | Machado | 7/8/2021 | 10:30:00 | 1930 | TDS | 702 | MG/L | N | WT | FALSE |

It should have marked the above as all but first TRUE right? lets try some more code below.

```
tds2 = pd.read_csv(path + 'testing/tds_testing.csv', parse_dates=['Sample Date'])
tds2 = tds2.drop_duplicates(subset=subset, keep=False)
print('tds2 shape 94:',tds2.shape)
```

> tds2 shape 94: (64, 11)

Comment: I would expect row 2 and 3 to be marked duplicate, because they are the same in the columns in `subset`. The same goes for row 4 and 5. But not row 1.

Comment: @Chrysophylaxs, Yes I agree. I thought I pasted in two different rows than the first. Anyway the problem still exists. I thought maybe it is encoding which if it is I don't know how to fix it. I tried `df_a["AC"] = df_a["AC"].str.encode("utf-8")` which did not work.

Comment: Your code looks fine to me, and runs fine when I use just the 5 provided rows. You'll need to do more debugging to figure it out :)

Comment: @Chrysophylaxs, Thanks . Any ideas on what should I try?

Comment: Try to isolate two rows you think would be marked as duplicate, but aren't, and compare them directly with `==` to confirm whether all values in those rows are actually equal. If one of them isn't then investigate why they're not and go from there

Answer (score 0):

If you the reader have a different idea please share...

Using the columns in `subset` from above you can use this code to detect the column that is the problem.

```
for col in subset:
    print(f'values of {col}\n', tds[col].value_counts())
```

the column that is the problem will have value counts of 1 when it should be a number greater than 1.

After running this code the problem is the Sample Time column.